# Node.js application works locally but not in Cloud

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry

My app.js file looks like this:

```
var port = (process.env.VMC_APP_PORT || 3000);
var host = (process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST || 'localhost');
var http = require('http');
var rip = require('./config.js');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        //do nothing...no response expected via http
}).listen(port, host);
```

The config.js file contains this (and more, but cut for brevity/relevance):

```
//several global.<property_name> assignments
global.mName                    = "Application Name";
//serveral more global.<property_name> assignments
...
...
require("./main.js");
```

The main.js file begins like this:

```
console.log(mName+" >>> Loading.");
```

When I run the application locally, it executes fine by running:

> node app.js

However, when I push the application to cloud foundry using the following command:

> vmc push [app_name] --runtime=node06

I get the following error:

> Creating Application: OK
>   Uploading Application:
>      Checking for available resources: OK
>      Processing resources: OK
>      Packing application: OK
>   Uploading (10K): OK
>   Push Status: OK 
>   Staging Application 'app_name': OK
>   Starting Application 'app_name': ..........................
>
> Error: Application [app_name] failed to start, logs information
>   below.
>
> ====> /logs/stderr.log <====
>
> node.js:134
>           throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
>           ^ ReferenceError: mName is not defined
>       at Object. (/var/vcap/data/dea/apps/app_name-0-6996d737ed319bcffaf696d653423d7c/app/main.js:6:1)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:411:26)
>       at Object..js (module.js:417:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:343:31)
>       at Function._load (module.js:302:12)
>       at Array. (module.js:430:10)
>       at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)

It seems like the properties I set in the global object in config.js are not being carried to the main.js.  I verified this by modifying the main.js to explicitly reference global.mName rather than just mName and that error went away, but another reference to a global object property then started to complain.

Since everything works fine locally without the explicit "global." reference, I don't think I should have to explicitly reference "global." for those variables.  Is there something I'm missing here?  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Go ahead and add the following package.json file to the root of your application directory:

```
{
  "name":"hello-node",
  "version":"0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "app.js"
  }
}
```

Now what the package.json is doing for you in this case is, it's telling cloudfoundry.com that your execution/start script file should be "app.js"

The reason you need to have this in place is because you also have a "main.js" file.
In cloudfoundry.com, by default the main.js file is over writing your app.js so its breaking your work.

So the package.json with the scripts object in it fixes the problem :-)